# Yii remember me login

Tags: yii, yii-extensions

I have set configuration:

```
'allowAutoLogin'=>true,
```

After successful login (with checked remember me checkbox) special cookie (with hash) is created. But after closing browser and opening website again I am not logged in but instead redirected to login page. When I look in application.log I have:

```
2014/07/30 09:44:11 [trace] [system.db.CDbCommand] Querying SQL: SELECT `itemname`
FROM `AuthAssignment`
WHERE itemname=:itemname AND userid=:userid. Bound with :itemname='Admin', :userid='10'
```

But after invoking filteraccessControler userId is set to 0

```
2014/07/30 09:44:11 [trace] [system.web.filters.CFilterChain] Running filter AController.filterforcedPasswordChange()
2014/07/30 09:44:11 [trace] [system.web.filters.CFilterChain] Running filter AController.filteraccessControl()
2014/07/30 09:44:11 [trace] [system.db.CDbCommand] Querying SQL: SELECT *
FROM `AuthAssignment`
WHERE userid=:userid. Bound with :userid=0
```

What could be the problem ?

Comment: After closing the browser and opening it again is the cookie still here?

Comment: Yes it exists but afterLogin it disappears. In beforeLogin i have got proper user ID

Comment: Are you using rights module?

Comment: Yes I am Why user ID is not passed there which methods ?